# How to control google maps hover area on circles?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Background: I have developed a web application which is based on Google Maps and it allows the user to collect a chain of LatLng positions with mouse clicks. (These positions are stored to the backend and later an app can draw shapes from these coordinates.) Once a click is registered, the program marks it as a colored circle on the map.

Problem: This worked well for months but since yesterday I notice a different behavior in Google maps: When I move the cursor to a new position for an intended next click and the cursor comes close to an already displayed circle, the cursor turns to hover mode (Index finger symbol) and the click cannot be registered. Principally, the phenomena happened in the past as well but with a far different sensitivity. In the past I had to move truly above the existing circle to get into this hover mode but now it happens when the cursor is just near. This gives me the problem that positions (clicks) cannot be registered in the required granularity anymore. For illustration, I add two photos from the screen.
The first case shows the problem. Even though the cursor is not above the existing circles (blue, yellow, red), it is in hover mode (index finger) and a click can not be collected. So no additional circle can be created at the given position.

[image]

The second picture shows the condition when the cursor has moved slightly further away from the position above. Now the cursor changed to the normal pointer mode and a click can be made for a new circle:

[image]

So it seems that the area around an object (here circle) which controls the cursor mode (hover or not) has increased in the last days by some changes in the Google maps program. In the past I was able to place circles very close to each other since the cursor did not fall into hover mode (index finger).

Question: Is there a way to control (e.g. in the map definition) the size of the hover area around an object? I have searched an entire day for such a parameter or a solution on a problem of that kind but have not found anything. If there is no way to control it, to whom could I address this issue @ Google?

JavaScript Code snippets:

A) The map initiation:

```js
  var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom:18,
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
    tilt: 0,
    draggableCursor: 'default',
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById("googleMap");
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
```

B) The circle creation:

```js
          var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          strokeColor: circleColor,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          fillColor: circleColor,
          fillOpacity: 1,
          map: map,
          center: workPosition[1],
          radius: 0.5
          })
```

Comment: How do you call the Maps API? Can you share the bootstrap? It would also be helpful to [share a self-contained sample of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sounds like the recent change in the experimental version is effecting you

Comment: as a workaround until this is checked insert v=3 (to use release version) in your script as stated 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

Answer (score 0):

Betofarina's comment above contains the correct answer. Thanks a lot! Adding "v=3" made Google maps to behave as in the past and my problem was solved. Now I can set new circles very narrow again as below (orange)

[image]

The relevant line of code is:

```js
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3">
</script>
```

Adding ?v=3 to this line did the job.